# Is that correct ?Any matrix is similar to a matrix which only has the element in the diagonal line and 1st row.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

**For any complex matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix  as follows:$$\begin{pmatrix}&\lambda_1 &k_{2} &... &k_{n}\\
& &\lambda_2 & &   \\
& & &... & \\
& & & &\lambda_n\\\end{pmatrix}$$that is ,only the elements on the diagonal line and the 1st row can be possibly non-zero，the rests are all $0$，and the diagonal elements are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$. Or in other words，for any linear operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$,one can find a group of basis of $V$，such that the matrix of $T$ has that shape under the basis.**

Here is my proof , but I don't know whether there are any bugs .

**$Proof$**: Use the induction on $\dim V$，when $\dim V=1$，the assertion is obviously true.

Suppose for all the vector spaces which dimensions is $\leq n-1$ the assertion is true, then for $\dim V=n$，we can assume $Tv_1=\lambda_1 v_1$, denote $U=\mathrm{span} [v_1]$, thus $$\dim V/U=n-1$$
By the induction assumption，there exists a group of basis of $V/U$, $(v_2+U,v_3+U,...,v_n+U)$，such that the quotient operator $T/U$ has the matrix as follows, :
$$\mathcal{M}(T/U)=\begin{pmatrix}&\lambda_2 &k_{2} &... &k_{n-1}\\
& &\lambda_3& & \\
& & &... &  \\
& & & &\lambda_n\\\end{pmatrix}$$
Since each egeinvalues of $T/U$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ , and:
$$\begin{align}
T/U(v_j+U)&=Tv_j+U\\
&=k_{j-1}v_1+\lambda_jv_j+ U\\
&\Rightarrow Tv_j=\lambda_jv_j+k'_jv_1
\end{align}$$
Here $j=2,...,n$，$k_1=\lambda_2$,(the last step comes from $U=\mathrm{span}[v_1]$) ,and $$Tv_1=\lambda_1v_1$$
One can deduce that 
$$\mathcal{M}(T)=\begin{pmatrix}&\lambda_1 &k'_{2} &... &k'_{n}\\
& &\lambda_2 & & \\
& & &... & \\
& & & &\lambda_n\\\end{pmatrix}$$
Which will end the proof.

I tried to find this result in some books , but I tried my best  , I couldn't find , so I  post it here , want to know is that a truth ?

Comment: The proof is false, because in your representation of $T/U$, you have $(T/U)(U+v_j)=k’_{j-1}(v_2+U)+\lambda_jv_j$.

Comment: "I've never seen this result in any linear algebra book". This is absurd. Schur triangulation is discussed in virtually every introductory linear algebra textbook. What linear algebra texts have you read?

Comment: @user1551 My apologize to my word , I will search it in the Wikipedia ! Thank you for telling me !

Comment: However, note that Schur triangulation is stronger than your result: you only need similarity, but Schur triangulation gives you *unitary* similarity/equivalence.